# Using javascript, how can I make a YouTube video go to fullscreen when a user clicks play?

Tags: javascript, youtube, fullscreen, swfobject, youtube-javascript-api

I have a page with a YouTube video on it. The client wants the video to go fullscreen when a user clicks play and bypass the usual step of clicking the fullscreen icon on the player.

I have been searching everywhere for an answer to this question and maybe it just isn't possible, but it seems  like it should be there. I haven't found any documentation of it in the YouTube Javascript API reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this can't be done.